# Tela de sinalização de pergunta em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Aparentemente isto não foi reportado aqui. Fui sinalizar uma pergunta e apareceu a seguinte tela:

[image: Tela Sem Traduzir]

Comment: Ainda nem a meia hora sinalizei e estava em português...

Comment: @JorgeB. Só para ter certeza, ele não clicou em Fechar, foi no Sinalizar. Para mim está aparecendo assim também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim é isso mesmo, agora está em Inglês mas já sinalizei hoje em português.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Espera eu sinalizei respostas e nas respostas não está tudo em inglês... http://i.imgur.com/tFCl9Io.png

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que por este motivo pararam de fazer as traduções, a cada mudança do layout (mesmo que pequena), muitas coisas voltam a estados anteriores, manter um comunidade em um idioma diferente realmente parece um pouco trabalhoso para a equipe do StackExchange.

Comment: Mudaram a tela toda de sinalizações. To traduzindo tudo agora.

Comment: No ar depois do próximo build