# Opções da Tela de Sinalização estão em Inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

Pessoal algumas partes da **Tela de Sinalização** estão em *Inglês*.

Acho que pode ser um Bug, ou pode ser que alguém tenha editado, de acordo com essas outras perguntas [Aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4434/precisando-de-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nas-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-sinaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2683/tela-de-sinaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-pergunta-em-ingl%C3%AAs)

**Desktop**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mobile**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente já corrigiram, o testo já voltou para PT-BR

Comment: Só pra notar: é PT e não PT-BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this was something that affected all of the international sites.  We've since corrected it and it should not happen anymore.

---

Sim, isso foi algo que afetou todos os sites localizados. Nós já corrigimos isso e isso não deveria mais acontecer.

Comment: É mas está acontecendo toda hora, com Botões e principalmente nas telas de Sinalização. Nem estou mais postando aqui pq cada hora aparece texto em Inglês em algum lugar...

Comment: Unfortunately, we are still in the middle of finding these errors and correcting the code that is causing them to revert to English.  Keep alerting me to anything else you find.  Thanks!